# DirectorySearcher get all domain controllers for a list of domains

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Currently I have 8 domains. Using the following code...

```
$listOfDCs = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain().DomainControllers

ForEach ($DC in $listOfDCs)
{
    Write-Host $DC
}
```

I get 32 controllers for the one domain. Any idea how I can extract the controllers for the other domains?

Note: I want to avoid using the quest cmdlets as much as possible.

The reason for this is the lastlogon property value is different for every dc in the domain. I'm just trying to grab the latest one. Here is the working code I have for this, but it does not pull the latest one...

```
$SamAccountName = "JohnDoe"
$domainSearchProperties = @('SamAccountName','LastLogon', 'DistinguishedName')
$domainDisplayOutputProperties = @('SamAccountName','LastLogon')
$domainConnector = 'www.myplayground.com'
$domainName = 'MyPlayground'
$outputFile = 'C:\Scripts\Tests\testresults.csv'

Function SearchSingleDomainAndExportContents
{
    Param ([String]$SamAccountName, [String]$LocalOutputFileWithPath, [String[]]$domainSearchProperties, [String[]]$domainDisplayOutputProperties, [String]$domainConnector, [String]$domainName)
    Write-Host "Starting sub-process to search with SamAccountName $SamAccountName in $domainName"
    $searchDomainResultsTable = powershell -command {
        Param ([String]$SamAccountName, [String]$LocalOutputFileWithPath, [String[]]$domainSearchProperties, [String[]]$domainDisplayOutputProperties, [String]$domainConnector, [String]$domainName)
        $domain = "LDAP://$domainConnector"
        $adDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($domain)
        $adSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($adDomain)
        $adSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(samAccountType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=805306368)(sAMAccountName=$SamAccountName))"
        $adSearcher.PageSize=1000
        $adSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange($domainSearchProperties) | out-Null
        $userRecords = $adSearcher.FindAll() | Where-Object {($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*Retired*")}
        $adSearcher.Dispose() | Out-Null
        [System.GC]::Collect() | Out-Null

        # The AD results are converted to an array of hashtables.
        $userPropertiesTable = @()
        foreach($record in $userRecords) {
            $hashUserProperty = @{}
            foreach($userProperty in $domainSearchProperties){
                if (($userProperty -eq 'objectGUID') -or ($userProperty -eq 'objectSid') -or ($userProperty -eq 'msExchMasterAccountSid')) {
                    if ($record.Properties[$userProperty]) {
                        $hashUserProperty.$userProperty = $record.Properties[$userProperty][0]
                    } else {
                        $hashUserProperty.$userProperty = $null
                    }
                } Else {
                    if ($record.Properties[$userProperty]) {
                        $hashUserProperty.$userProperty = ($record.Properties[$userProperty] -join '; ').trim('; ')
                    } else {
                        $hashUserProperty.$userProperty = $null
                    }
                } #end Else
            } #end ForEach
            $userPropertiesTable += New-Object PSObject -Property $hashUserProperty
        } #end ForEach
        [System.GC]::Collect() | Out-Null

        # Fixes the property values to be a readable format before exporting to csv file
        $listOfBadDateValues = '9223372036854775807', '9223372036854770000', '0'
        $maxDateValue = '12/31/1600 5:00 PM'
        $valuesToFix = @('lastLogonTimestamp', 'AccountExpires', 'LastLogon', 'pwdLastSet', 'objectGUID', 'objectSid', 'msExchMasterAccountSid')
        $valuesToFixCounter = 0
        $valuesToFixFound = @($false, $false, $false, $false, $false, $false, $false)

        ForEach ($valueToFix in $valuesToFix)
        {
            if ($domainDisplayOutputProperties -contains $valueToFix)
            {
                $valuesToFixFound[$valuesToFixCounter] = $true
            }
            $valuesToFixCounter++
        }

        $tableFixedValues = $userPropertiesTable | % { 
            if ($valuesToFixFound[0]) {
                if ($_.lastLogonTimestamp) {
                    $_.lastLogonTimestamp = ([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)).ToString('g')
                }
            }; if ($valuesToFixFound[1]) {
                if (($_.AccountExpires) -and ($listOfBadDateValues -contains $_.AccountExpires)) {
                    $_.AccountExpires = ""
                } else {
                    if (([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.AccountExpires)).ToString('g') -eq $maxDateValue) {
                        $_.AccountExpires = ""
                    } Else {
                        $_.AccountExpires = ([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.AccountExpires)).ToString('g')
                    }
                }
            }; if ($valuesToFixFound[2]) {
                if (($_.LastLogon) -and ($listOfBadDateValues -contains $_.LastLogon)) {
                    $_.LastLogon = ""
                } else {
                    if (([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)).ToString('g') -eq $maxDateValue) {
                        $_.LastLogon = ""
                    } Else {
                        $_.LastLogon = ([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)).ToString('g')
                    }
                }
            }; if ($valuesToFixFound[3]) {
                if (($_.pwdLastSet) -and ($listOfBadDateValues -contains $_.pwdLastSet)) {
                    $_.pwdLastSet = ""
                } else {
                    if (([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.pwdLastSet)).ToString('g') -eq $maxDateValue) {
                        $_.pwdLastSet = ""
                    } Else {
                        $_.pwdLastSet = ([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.pwdLastSet)).ToString('g')
                    }
                }
            }; if ($valuesToFixFound[4]) {
                if ($_.objectGUID) {
                    $_.objectGUID = ([guid]$_.objectGUID).Guid
                } Else {
                    $_.objectGUID = ""
                }
            }; if ($valuesToFixFound[5]) {
                if ($_.objectSid) {
                    $_.objectSid  = (New-Object Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($_.objectSid, 0)).Value
                } Else {
                    $_.objectSid = ""
                }
            }; if ($valuesToFixFound[6]) {
                if ($_.msExchMasterAccountSid) {
                    $_.msExchMasterAccountSid  = (New-Object Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($_.msExchMasterAccountSid, 0)).Value
                } Else {
                    $_.msExchMasterAccountSid = ""
                }
            };$_}
            [System.GC]::Collect() | Out-Null

            $sortedUserPropertiesTable = $tableFixedValues | Select-Object $domainDisplayOutputProperties
            $finalDomainUserPropertiesTable = $sortedUserPropertiesTable | Select-Object -Property @{Name="Domain Name";Expression={$domainName}}, *
            [System.GC]::Collect() | Out-Null

            return $finalDomainUserPropertiesTable
    } -args $SamAccountName, $LocalOutputFileWithPath, $domainSearchProperties, $domainDisplayOutputProperties, $domainConnector, $domainName
    [System.GC]::Collect() | Out-Null
    Write-Host "Search Complete."
    Write-Host ""

    $searchDomainResultsTable | Export-Csv $outputFile -NoTypeInformation -Force
}
```

This will pull the data from only 1 dc. The issue with this is, there are other dc's where lastlogon contains a later date, and that is the one I'm after. So I need to query all dc's, and then just export the latest lastlogon date for that SamAccountName.

Comment: Why not just use the `lastLogonTimestamp` attribute?

Comment: it actually has a much earlier date than LastLogon. For example...

`LastLogon for this dc in this domain = 2/8/2016 10:00am`, `latest LastLogon for all dc's in this domain = 2/10/2016 11:00am`, `lastLogonTimestamp for this dc in this domain = 2/1/2016 9:00am`,

Comment: See ["The LastLogonTimeStamp Attribute" - "What it was designed for and how it works"](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works/) for more about the `lastLogonTimestamp` attribute. With this understanding, why can't you use it?

Comment: I understand what you are saying, however given the property value is set to be recorded only every 15 days, it does not serve the main purpose of the script. The purpose of the script is to get the real last logon of the user. The most current date is pulled from `LastLogon` and not `lastLogonTimestamp`. Also, in your given link... "With default settings in place the lastLogontimeStamp will be 9-14 days behind the current date."

Comment: Getting the most recent `lastLogon` attribute from all potential domain controllers is very inefficient. If you really need this, one typical recommendation is to create a logon script that writes a small text file somewhere containing the `sAMAccountName` and the current time.

Comment: I don't have those kind of permissions. I'm not an admin, just a hired scripter. It may be inefficient, but it is what they are asking for (as many things they ask for are inefficient). I'm not even sure why they want this, maybe because they want to use the output file for some other automated task. Who knows. But in the end, this is what the customer wants. Note, they already have a script for this using the quest cmdlets, but they say it's too slow and they want to use my code with the .net directorysearcher.

Comment: I would suggest that, as a consultant, part of the job is to determine the actual requirements and assist them with suggestions when they say they want things that are inefficient. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Consultants at this company are not trusted with the project scope and are only on a need to know basis. I just need to find out how to get a list of dc's from each given domain. If there is a way to do that, I can figure out the rest.

Comment: You don't need to use the quest cmdlets. Just use the Active Directory PowerShell module that comes with RSAT

Comment: Not allowed to download the rsat tools in my company. It's either quest or the .net class.

Comment: RSAT is a standard Windows component. There should be no justification needed to install when required for a project...

Comment: I tried, was told no. I explained that it's from microsoft and embedded with windows, but they want everything standardized. Plus, I don't have rights/permissions to install anything. I don't really want to get too far off track here. If there is no way to find a list of dc's on different domains using directoryservices, I'll just have to use quest. `$DCs = get-QADComputer -computerRole 'DomainController' -IncludedProperties distinguishedname | where {$_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*Retired*"}`

Comment: But the Quest cmdlets are not standard (?!), and the...never mind...good luck with your project...<shaking my head incredulously>

Comment: "<shaking my head incredulously>", something I do everyday here. Just a few more paychecks, then my student loans are paid off and I'm leaving this company. I want to work for a company where I can at least be trusted with the project scope, and my next requirement will be working with a team that uses agile.

Comment: Good luck with that first requirement. I work as a vendor at a large software company based out of Redmond, WA, and we rarely get to know the scope of things, or have real visibility into things. We manage our aspect of the service, and just work with what we're given.

Comment: In most windows domains I've come across all the DCs are DNS servers and most of the time people don't deploy standalone DNS servers, so often you can just do "nslookup domain.local" to get a list of IPs of the DCs, if they happened to deploy a standalone DNS server, you just won't get a result when you query it.  Not 100% foolproof, but in a default environment it works well.

Answer (score 1):

If your computer is already a domain member, locating all other domains in the forest is easier than you might think.

Simply search for `crossRef` objects (these are the links between database partitions on the domain controller and the logical naming contexts in the forest - such as domains) that has their `systemFlag` attribute value set to `0x3`. These are all stored in the same container in the Configuration Naming Context:

```
# connect to the RootDSE - the yellow pages of Active Directory
$RootDSE  = [adsi]"LDAP://RootDSE"
# grab the distinguished name of the forest-wide configuration naming context
$ConfigDN = $RootDSE.configurationNamingContext.ToString()

# Create a new directory search
$ConfigSearcher = [adsisearcher]""

# Configure the searcher to look for domain cross-ref's
$ConfigSearcher.SearchRoot = "LDAP://$ConfigDN"
$ConfigSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=crossRef)(systemFlags=3))"
[void]$ConfigSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(@('dnsRoot','nCName','nETBIOSName'))
$Domains = $ConfigSearcher.FindAll()

# Grab only the three most interesting pieces of info
# The fully qualified DNS name, e.g.  domain.forest.tld
# The NetBIOS shortname, e.g. DOMAIN
# The distinguished name to the domain root, e.g DC=domain,DC=forest,DC=tld 
$Domains = $Domains |Select @{Name="DomainFQDN";Expression={$_.Properties['dnsRoot']}},@{Name='NetBIOSName';Expression={$_.Properties['nETBIOSName']}},@{Name='DN';Expression={$_.Properties['nCName']}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I already have a module built where the domains are hardcoded. What I need to have it auto search for is the domain controllers. For example... domain1.com = 32 domain controllers, domain2.com = 28 domain controllers, domain3.com = 2 domain controllers, and so forth... Then I will have to redo my code to have the user specify the domain, and have it loop a search through every dc for that domain, calculate which `LastLogon` is the latest, and export only that value for that `SamAccountName` to a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You can get other domains using the .Net Domain class, like you're doing for your current domain. First you need to create context for the domain that you are targeting, and then you can get the domain info, including the DCs.

```
$DomainList = 'Domain1.com','Domain2.com','Domain3.com','Domain4.com','Domain5.com','Domain6.com','Domain7.com','Domain8.com'
$AllDCs = $DomainList | ForEach{
    $DomContxt = new-object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext -ArgumentList ('Domain',$_)
    $Domain = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetDomain($DomContxt)
    $Domain.DomainControlers
}
```

Comment: I think OP is trying to "autodiscover" the other domains in the forest

Comment: interesting, I didn't know DomainControlers existed as a return value for the DirectoryServices assembly... After I finish my logic, I might try this out... Right now they wanted this to be done 2 days ago, and so far I have nothing for them... question is `'Domain'` the value iterator in the ForEach loop for the array of domains, or is it a default value for that `DirectoryContext -ArgumentList`?

Comment: The term `'Domain'` is a value from a `DirectoryContextType` list found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.directorycontexttype(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Also from command line you can ask dns server for ip address of all domain controllers

nslookup.exe domain1